# How can I solve the equation $x'(t)=y(t)^2, y'(t)=x(t)^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the differential equation

$$
\begin{cases}
x'(t)=y(t)^2 \\
y'(t)=x(t)^2
\end{cases}
$$

with the initial conditions $x(0)=x_0, y(0)=y_0$?

A little bit code in *Mathematica* can give the result, but just a pile of stuff as `InverseFunction` and `Hypergeometric2F1` etc, which is useless.

Comment: At a glance, in the special case $y_0 = x_0$ we can specialize to the case $y(t) = x(t)$, for which the solution is $x(t) = 1 / (x_0^{-1} - t)$. For the general case one can differentiate and substitute twice to eliminate $y$ and its derivatives, but the resulting equation looks pretty unpleasant. Is there a reason why you think Mathematica misses a closed-form solution here?

Comment: "which is useless" - it depends on what you need the solution for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=\pm \sqrt{x'}$$

Leaving out the $\pm$ ambiguity for now:

$$y'=\frac{x''}{2\sqrt{x'}}$$

$$\frac{x''}{2\sqrt{x'}}=x^2$$

---

$$x'=u(x)$$

$$x''=u u'$$

---

$$\sqrt{u} ~u'=2 x^2$$

$$\frac{2}{3} u^{3/2}=\frac{2}{3} x^3+c_1$$

$$u=(x^3+c_1)^{2/3}$$

---

$$x'=(x^3+c_1)^{2/3}$$

$$dt=\frac{dx}{(x^3+c_1)^{2/3}}$$

Integrating we have the function $t(x)$, which we need to invert to find $x(t)$, if it's possible to do explicitly.

The integral on the right can be found in terms of hypergeometric function (hence, Mathematica output), using the Euler integral (see wikipedia and other sources)

Comment: I don't think the coefficient of $dx$ has a closed-form antiderivative.

Comment: @Travis, we can find it in terms of hypergeometric function for sure, which is probably what Mathematica did

Comment: I agree (I don't consider hypergeometric functions closed-form), but OP says outright he's not willing to use those functions. I do doubt he has a choice here, though.

Comment: What I want to know is actually the range of the possible $t$. Although the last integral can't be write *explicitly*, it's sufficient for me.

Comment: @Stone-Zeng In the future I suggest at least mentioning what you actually want to know in your original question; among other things, this will help others write more relevant answers. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem As is the case here, extracting some information about the domain of a maximal solution can be easier than finding the solution explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

From

$$
\dot x = y^2\\
\dot y = x^2 
$$

we have

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2}{y^2}\Rightarrow y^3=x^3+C_0
$$

and then

$$
\dot x = \left(x^3+C_0\right)^{2/3}\\
\dot y = \left(y^3-C_0\right)^{2/3}
$$

etc

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\begin{cases}
x'(t)=y(t)^2 \\
y'(t)=x(t)^2
\end{cases} \implies \frac {dx}{dy}=\frac {y^2}{x^2}$$
$$\implies \frac {x^3}3=\frac {y^3}3+K \implies x^3=y^3+C$$
With initial condition 
$$C= {x^3}- {y^3}={x^3_0}- {y^3_0}$$